# не доходят письма на почту

Tags: php

делал новый сайт, и переносил обработчик для формы с старого, на старом все работает, когда перенёс на новом перестали доходить письма на почту, не могу понять в чем проблема

```
<?php 
            header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" .
                "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"" . "\r\n" .
                "From: =?utf-8?b?". base64_encode($name_from) ."?= <".$mail_from.">" . "\r\n";
              $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
            $first3 = substr($host,0,4);
            if($first3 === 'www.') $host = substr($host,4,strlen($host));
            $domain = "";
            if(empty($domain)) $domain = $host;
            $mail_to = "dmitrobolva12@gmail.com";
            $mail_from = "no-reply@".$domain;
            $name_from = "Трезвый водитель заявка на вакансию";


              $phone = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['phone'])); 
                $name = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
                  $age = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['age'])); 
                    $exp = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['exp'])); 
                      $place = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['place'])); 
                        $reg = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['reg'])); 
                          $msg = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['msg']));
                            $email = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['mail']));

              $picture = ""; 

              // Если поле выбора вложения не пустое - закачиваем его на сервер 

              if (!empty($_FILES['mail_file']['tmp_name'])) 

              { 

                // Закачиваем файл 

                $path = $_FILES['mail_file']['name']; 

                if (copy($_FILES['mail_file']['tmp_name'], $path)) $picture = $path; 

              } 

              $thm = "$name_from";

             $msg=" ФИО: $name<br />
                    Возраст: $age <br />
                    Стаж вождения: $exp <br />
                    Район проживания: $place <br />
                    Район регистрации: $reg <br />
                    Email: $email <br />
                    Телефон: $phone<br />";

              $mail_to = "dmitrobolva12@gmail.com";

              // Отправляем почтовое сообщение 

              if(empty($picture)) mail($mail_to, $thm, $msg, $headers); 

              else send_mail($mail_to, $thm, $msg, $picture); 
              unlink($picture);
              // Вспомогательная функция для отправки почтового сообщения с вложением 

              function send_mail($to, $thm, $html, $path) 

              { 


                $fp = fopen($path,"r"); 

                if (!$fp) 

                { 

                  print "Файл $path не может быть прочитан"; 

                  exit(); 

                } 

                $file = fread($fp, filesize($path)); 

                fclose($fp); 



                $boundary = "--".md5(uniqid(time())); // генерируем разделитель 

                $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 

                $headers .="Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\n"; 

                $multipart .= "--$boundary\n"; 

                $kod = 'utf-8'; // или $kod = 'windows-1251'; 

                $multipart .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=$kod\n"; 

                $multipart .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quot-Printed\n\n";


                $multipart .= "$html\n\n"; 



                $message_part = "--$boundary\n"; 

                $message_part .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\n"; 

                $message_part .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n"; 

                $message_part .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = \"".$path."\"\n\n"; 

                $message_part .= chunk_split(base64_encode($file))."\n"; 

                $multipart .= $message_part."--$boundary--\n"; 



                if(!mail($to, $thm, $multipart, $headers)) 

                { 

                  echo "К сожалению, письмо не отправлено"; 

                  exit(); 

                } 

              } 

            ?>
```

Comment: Логи покажите серверные. Что за почтовый сервер/сервис в системе? Postfix?

Comment: я не силен в этом, если вы более точно сформулируете или подскажете где посмотреть, я вам смогу ответить, но могу так же показать обработчик почти такой же только без файла который работает без проблем

Comment: Сайты на одном и том же сервере? Там где, у вас `echo "К сожалению, письмо не отправлено"`, выведите ещё  `print_r(error_get_last())`.

Comment: нет, пока что сайты на разных серверах но потом когда доработаю перенесу на тот же где и старый, я так понимаю проблема в файле, без файла письма доходят, как только добавляю обработку для файла, перестают доходить

Comment: если это зависит от сервера то, может оно и заработает когда перенесу

Comment: На одном сервере у вас настроена почта, на другом нет. В это всё дело, думаю.

Comment: Вы используете функцию, mail (а значит локальный сервер отправки - настройка в php.ini), есть вариант использования phpmailer без настройки локального сервера

Comment: спасибо, попробую перенести и отправить с того на котором уже работал

Comment: просто удивительно что mail я и использую и с файлом и без, с файлом не отправляет, без файла отправляет

Comment: Пожалуйста, пользуйтесь библиотеками (Swift Mailer, например) по отправке почты. `try ... catch ...` и вы всегда будете знать причину проблемы.